# What are the "expressive" parts of a language actually called?

Tags: computational-linguistics, constructed-language

Languages provide ways to express:

1. Ordering

   - Temporal (yesterday, today), Spatial (above, below, before, after, inside, outside, ...), Quantitative (larger, smaller,...)
2. Relationships

   - Spatial (composed of), Social / hierarchies.
3. Specifiers (?) (this, that, other)
4. Questions / uncertainty
5. Possession (?) (Mine, yours, etc)

What is the terminology that is used to refer to these things? Are they finite (?). Is there any form of catalogue that lists languages versus what these languages can express?

My motivation is to apply these to understanding "constrained" languages that are trying to convey specific concepts and therefore have to be composed of specific distinct parts.

Comment: "Semantic categories" is one way to talk about them. You could get some interesting lists and classifications from a number of sources. I'd recommend Foley's _Anthropological Linguistics_ and Frawley's _Linguistic Semantics_, which cover much of the same ground from slightly different perspectives.

Comment: @jlawler Thank you, an answer along the content of the books (if you have them handy) that is relevant to this question would be the currently "accepted" for this question I guess.